# How to select the first element in the dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to select the first option in all select tags on my page using jquery.

tried this:

```
$('select option:nth(0)').attr("selected", "selected");
```

But didn't work

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Try this out...

```
$('select option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Another option would be this, but it will only work for one drop down list at a time as coded below:

```
var myDDL = $('myID');
myDDL[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

Take a look at this post on how to set based on value, its interesting but won't help you for this specific issue:

[Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-selected-value-of-drop-down-list-with-jquery)

Comment: just change myID to select as i want all select tags

Comment: now in jQuery you can access the properties via the `.prop()` method.  So you could use `$("select").prop("selectedIndex",0);` for a quick way to select the first option on all dropdowns.

Comment: Do you know if this will trigger a 'change' event in all browsers just by setting the attribute?  It seems to in Chrome, but haven't tested it extensively.  I was thinking about adding another `$('select').trigger('change');` just in case.  Thanks!

Comment: `var myDDL = $('myID')` should have hash in the selector to become `var myDDL = $('#myID')`

Comment: This method works well for me:
`$('select option').first().prop('selected',true);`

Comment: For my case, I like Chris Barr's method. Note, it will not fire the onchange event. The first code example in the answer will. Options are good. (no pun intended)

Answer (score 15):

Your selector is wrong, you were probably looking for

```
$('select option:nth-child(1)')
```

This will work also:

```
$('select option:first-child')
```

Comment: CSS nth-child selector index starts at 1, not 0

Answer (score 11):

Ana alternative Solution for RSolgberg, which fires the `'onchange'` event if present:

```
$("#target").val($("#target option:first").val());
```

[How to make first option of <select > selected with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414276/how-to-make-first-option-of-select-selected-with-jquery)

Comment: This works better than the accepted answer if you have to change the selected option multiple times. E.g. if you filter your options and display part of them.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#DDLID").val( $("#DDLID option:first-child").val() );
```

[For Complete Drop Down List Operations using Jquery](http://knowfreely.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=228%3adrop-down-list-operations-in-jquery&catid=20%3ajquery-and-net&Itemid=39)

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is probably:

```
$("select option:first-child")
```

What this code

```
attr("selected", "selected");
```

is doing is setting the "selected" attribute to "selected"

If you want the selected options, regardless of whether it is the first-child, the selector is:

```
$("select").children("[selected]")
```

Comment: Replace `attr` with `prop` if you're using jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple `javascript` solution which works in most cases:

```
document.getElementById("selectId").selectedIndex = "0";
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering because the previous answers have stopped working with the latest version of jQuery.  I don't know when it stopped working, but the documentation says that .prop() has been the preferred method to get/set properties since jQuery 1.6.

This is how I got it to work (with jQuery 3.2.1):

```
$('select option:nth-child(1)').prop("selected", true);
```

I am using knockoutjs and the change bindings weren't firing with the above code, so I added .change() to the end.

Here's what I needed for my solution:

```
$('select option:nth-child(1)').prop("selected", true).change();
```

See .prop() notes in the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check the text of selected option regardless if its the 1st child.

```
var a = $("#select_id option:selected").text();
alert(a); //check if the value is correct.
if(a == "value") {-- execute code --}
```

Comment: Saved me a second search.  This is pretty much what I was looking for, although I was more interested in changing the value than checking it.  `$('#myID option:selected').text('NEW STRING');`

Answer (score 1):

```
    var arr_select_val=[];

    $("select").each(function() { 
        var name=this.name;
            arr_select_val[name]=$('select option:first-child').val();
    });


// Process the array object
     $('.orders_status_summary_div').print(arr_select_val);
```