# Setting first <select> option as selected

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to set the first  of a few  to set as selected

I have

```
<select name="id[21]" class="atributosSort">
  <option value="107">1. Sin adaptadores de video (+$45)</option>
  <option value="108">2. Mini Displayport to DVI (+$112)</option>
  <option value="109">3. Mini Displayport to VGA</option>
</select>
```

I tried

```
jQuery(".atributosSort")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

and

```
jQuery(".atributosSort option:first").attr('selected','selected');
```

both discussed at
[How to make first option of <select > selected with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414276/how-to-make-first-option-of-select-selected-with-jquery)
but when I inspect the DOM, no attribute is added to any

I'm using jQuery() because I'm in noConflict mode. Could that be the issue?

When I run both attempts to get the selected value I don't get any error in the Script Console

Another thing that might be relevant is that I'm sorting the options with this

```
function sortDropDownListByText() {
// Loop for each select element on the page.
jQuery("select").each(function() {

    // Keep track of the selected option.
    var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();

    // Sort all the options by text. I could easily sort these by val.
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery("option", jQuery(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    }));

    // Select one option.
    //jQuery(this).val(selectedValue);

});
}

  // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 jQuery(document).ready(sortDropDownListByText);
```

I commented jQuery(this).val(selectedValue); out because I thought that that line was setting some option as selected and then I can't override it but that makes no difference.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
jQuery(".atributosSort option:first-child").attr("selected", true);
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I am using "Select one..." as my first option, with no value defined. I found this works for me:

```
//for elements having classname, get the first option and make it selected
$('.classname').find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');
```

This is similar to the one @NeXXeuS posted, but will do it for all your select fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".atributosSort")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

by Bill the Lizard♦

is the best answer, it doesnt bug with selected attribute on select.

Answer (score 1):

for newer version of jQuery:

```
$(".atributosSort").prop("selectedIndex", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing that when `$(document).ready(...)` ?

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".atributosSort")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

Comment: try this:
jQuery(documnet).ready(function(){jQuery(".atributosSort")[0].selectedIndex = 0;});

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: (putting parentheses after "sortDropDownListByText" in the "ready" statement)

```
// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 jQuery(document).ready(sortDropDownListByText(););
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code before? I use it for reset my dropdowns on too many projects using jQuery :

```
// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 $("#yourTarget").val($("#yourTarget option:first").val());
```

I Hope this could help you.