# display default as first option in select box without changing order

Tags: jquery, html, select

Is it possible to have a default option displayed in select box without changing the order of the other options?

```
<select>
    <option>
    1
    </option>
    <option>
    2
    </option>
    <option>
    3
    </option>
    <option>
    4
    </option>
    <option>
    5
    </option>
</select>
```

1. Default 1 is displayed:

[image: 1 is first in option list so it is displayed first]
 2. I want 3 displayed as default without changing order of option list:

[image: I want to display 3 a defualt]

Comment: May be this helps you: [how-to-make-first-option-of-select-selected-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414276/how-to-make-first-option-of-select-selected-with-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$("select").val($("select option[value='fb']").val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qu5fF/

or if you are using jquery 1.6 or higher use `prop`

```
$("select option[value='fb']").prop("selected",true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qu5fF/1/

for jquery version lower then 1.6 you can use `.attr`

```
$("select option[value='fb']").attr("selected","selected");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qu5fF/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the element at the 0 index.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var elem = document.getElementById('<%= DropDown.ClientID %>');
   var myNewOption = new Option(val.Name, val.ID);
   elem .options[elem .options.length] = myNewOption;
</script>
```

Comment: Would your list items be added dynamically from code behind or are they static?