# set the first value in Dropdown list as default value in php

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

How to set the first value that comes in the dropdown list as the default value in php? The first value should be by default selected when i open my page

Comment: did you use `selected` attribute of html ?

Comment: Show your code so that we can solve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achievable using `selected` attribute of selectbox:

```
<select name="youselectbox">
<option value="1" selected>Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>

</select>
```

**Edit :**

Give your selectbox a id say "selectme"

```
<select name="youselectbox" id="selectme">
```

Then on load use this jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#selectme").prop("selectedIndex", 0); // here 0 means select first option

});
```

For more information [SEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414276/how-to-make-first-option-of-select-selected-with-jquery) and [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/HE44x/)

Comment: The values in the dropdowns are dynamic i.e they are coming from the database.I need to set the first value whichever comes in the dropdown as the default selected value.I am not aware of which values will come.They keep on changing.

Answer (score 0):

With `selected` attribute within the option tag, you set the selected default value of your drop-down.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo"  selected>Volvo</option> # default selected option
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT :**

For Dynamic Drop-down menu: PHP Code as below

```
$("#target option:first").attr('selected','selected');
```

When setting attr selected doesn't work if there's already a selected attribute. The code I use now will first unset the selected attribute, then select the first option.

```
$('#target').removeAttr('selected').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: The values in the dropdowns are dynamic i.e they are coming from the database.I need to set the first value whichever comes in the dropdown as the default selected value.I am not aware of which values will come.They keep on changing.

Comment: @user3391126 : check out my Edited Answer, it may help you.