# Click trigger on select box doesn't work in jQuery 

Tags: jquery

How can a dropdown list can be opened with a trigger?

Here is the code which doesn't work:

```
$('select').trigger('click');
```

Just for note - mousedown and mouseup also doesn't work.

Comment: Think this is the solution you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-selected-value-of-drop-down-list-with-jquery

Comment: I've got this to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10136523/2541

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Comment: did you figured out any working solution, btw I'm trying to open select2 (jquery plugin) ?

Comment: **State of the art solution** for this quest: Increase the (vertical) size of the dropdown and style it (like `position:absolute`) that it looks open. That works cross-browser and is pretty simple.

Answer (score 13):

```
$('select').children('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':selected'))
    { $(this).trigger('change');  }
});
```

Comment: This might fire other attached events which you probably dont want.

Answer (score 9):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible. Even if you trigger a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) the drop down list won't open like if the user clicked on it. If you want to change the currently selected value with a new one you could use the [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function. I guess the only solution is to simulate the whole UI look and feel of a `select` element using divs.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't want to change value, just want to open list... It seems that there isn't propertly solution for this...

Comment: it's [explicitly denied by spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#trusted-events), @sasa :(

Answer (score 8):

Took me a while but found a solution:

(Chrome & Safari ONLY)

```
function open(elem) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/GR9jU/

Comment: Close. This works in Chrome & Safari, but doesn't work in Firefox or IE.

Comment: On chrome Version 75.0.3770.27 it's not working. 
But in Safari Version 12.1 (14607.1.40.1.4) It's working fine.

Comment: yeah @BijayRai it was [removed](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5718803933560832)

Answer (score 5):

There is no proper way to click on a dropdown programmatically.

You can either select an option via:

```
$('#sourceOptions>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', 'selected');
```

If you want to simulate a user click: you have to do it as @Renso says it:

```
$('#sourceOptions>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trigger give it a size.
This simply opens the select (tested in Chrome):

`/////// $('select').trigger('click');
$('select')[0].size = 10;`