# The click event does not seem to work with a select element in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Click trigger on select box doesn't work in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895608/click-trigger-on-select-box-doesnt-work-in-jquery)

I am trying to do the following to simulate a click on a select element:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#' + id).trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

This works in Firefox but not IE. Is there some possible work around for IE?

Comment: what is your element id. I suspect its not valid html. The code you posted is fine for IE.

Comment: Doesn't work in firefox either. You cannot emulate a click on a select element (as in, to make it open)

Comment: @Esailija - That might explain my problems. With my code the way it is I thought it was working. Do you happen to know if you can send any event to a select. For example a mouse event ?

Comment: @Anne You can't make it open by itself, sorry. And this doesn't work in firefox for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NmhwQ/2/ If that works for you in firefox then your firefox is different from mine.

Comment: Out of interest what's the end goal here? Are you trying to auto select a value from a drop-down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try attaching your custom click event handler, before triggering the click event:

```
$('#' + id).bind('click', function() {
     alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: This works but not what's needed. I would like to send a click event to the select to cause it to open.