# open dropdown list from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam trying to show the dropdown option when javascript function is called.
but eventually iam not succeed on this. need help
Here is my code:

```
<script>
function showState(str){ 
$('#Acntname').trigger('click');

}
</script>
...
<select class="input_panel" id="Acntname" > 
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">Equity Share Capital</option>
<option value="2">Deprication Fund</option>  </select>

<input type="text" class="input_panel" id="accountname" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/>
```

i used triggered function to open the dropdown but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to show the dropdown or fetch selected dropdown option value?

Comment: Found something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895608/click-trigger-on-select-box-doesnt-work-in-jquery)

Answer (score 14):

Here you go..you can do this by dispatching mousedown event on dropdown..

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wUjb/7/)

**JS:**

```
window.showState = function (str) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('Acntname');
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

**EDIT: This works perfectly in [Chrome <53](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832), not sure for Firefox and IE.**

Comment: This won't work for folks browsing with TAB on their keyboard.

Comment: this works only in Chrome...!!!!

Comment: This worked for me! I just used `dropdown.focus(); try { /* answer's chrome only code here */ } catch(e){}` to prevent it from messing anything up in Firefox/IE. Chrome only is better than nothing!

Comment: @smclark89 Actually, you can make it work with tab. Juse use a `keydown` event listener with `if (event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 13) { /* code here */ }` to capture the tab and enter keys.

Comment: this works in firefox 35.0.1

Comment: Guys can u Please create Demo

Comment: @Sopo Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/2wUjb/7/

Comment: I tested it on Chrome Version 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit) and it does not work. It worked on Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit) though...

Comment: @juacompe It's been [removed due to "security"](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5718803933560832)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('Acntname');
var len = sel.options.length;

sel.setAttribute('size', len);
```

Set the size back to 1 to close it

Comment: Does not work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to `toggle` the `drop down` on `triggering other element`.

If you want to select the value of `select box` on `keyup event` of `textbox` then try this,

```
function showState(str){ 
   //  alert(str);
   $('#Acntname option[value="'+str+'"]').prop('selected',true);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wUjb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't open the dropdown list but there is a **semi-solution** you could do the following

to "open" the list:

```
$("#Acntname").attr("size","3");
```

and

```
$("#Acntname").attr("size","1");
```

to close the list.

Comment: We can open dropdown list..check this..http://jsfiddle.net/2wUjb/7/

Comment: @Nikhil your solution is not working in Firefox and IE at least not for me.

Comment: oh..I am checking it in chrome..let me check into firefox and ie also.