# Select and open a selectbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I know I can focus and select an HTML selectbox drop-down with jquery:

```
<script>
    $('#otherbox').on('change', function() {
        $("#selbox").focus();
        $("#selbox").select();
    });
</script>
```

But this only focuses the selectbox but it doesn't open it, I still have to click on the select-element with the mouse to open it.

How can I automatically open the selectbox by another event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895608/click-trigger-on-select-box-doesnt-work-in-jquery

Comment: or even better http://stackoverflow.com/a/10136523/142161 which shows a chrome only way of doing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652085/open-dropdown-list-from-javascript-function

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

- you can either try to use `MouseEvent` to simulate the `mousedown` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent + check the links in the comments)
- or you can create an invisible div with `select`'s options duplicated in it right under the `select` itself and upon a `click` event just make that div visible, thus emulating an open dropdown.