# HTML <select> open on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to open HTML `<select>` was open in my demo application. By searching I found the solution as setting size like.

```
document.getElementById('Selectlist').size = 13;
```

[Select list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCVaF.png)

but after applying this I have design a issue. Which is not like a `<select>` box.

Help me to other solution for this.

Comment: Why not use some plugin like selec2?

Comment: Sooo.... the problem is what? What is this design issue you are referring to?

Answer (score 3):

The solution you use `document.getElementById('Selectlist').size = 13;` is for making the `<select>` dropdown to `<select>` box. Setting the size to select box will increase the `<select>` height only. Moreover setting the size to `<select>` is like increasing the height not like opening the drop down. FYR [open dropdown list from javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652085/open-dropdown-list-from-javascript-function)