# jQuery trigger("click") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone please explain what is wrong with the pasted code. It shows alert on hover but does not perform click event like I expect, and click does not work on either `<a>` tag or `<select>` tag. My purpose is to expand the `select` element *on hover* by triggering *click* event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="linkElement" href="www.google.co.uk">click</a>

    <select name="cars" id="selectElemet">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#selectElement").mouseover(function () {
                $("#selectElement").trigger("click");
            });

            $("#linkElement").mouseover(function () {
                alert('here');
                $("#linkElement").trigger("click");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is your click event?

Comment: instead of $("#linkElement").trigger("click"); use $("#linkElement").click();

Comment: tried Both $("#linkElement").click(); and  $("#selectElement").get(0).click(); still not working

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is, it is not possible to programatically expand the select element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652085/open-dropdown-list-from-javascript-function

Comment: Do u want to show select options list during hover? Is my understanding right?

Comment: @Arun P Johny Thankyou for the links

Comment: @Jagadeesh yes thats the idea

Comment: If so, please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover and let me know whether it is useful for you or not? Since Select tag is very difficult tag in html. We can't overwrite its property. So we have to move options are in ul li tags..

Comment: I think this answer is the closest to this question. It also is more generic in solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4473353/115237

Answer (score 3):

`.trigger("click")` will not actually click the element, it will only trigger click handler attached with the element. Since you have not attached any none is triggered.

You can use native `.click()`

```
$("#selectElement").get(0).click(); //get(0) returns reference to DOM element
```

Comment: I don't think calling the native click will solve the OPs issue

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Agree, Just provide the reason why `trigger()` is not working

Answer (score 2):

There'a a spelling mistake in your ID attribute. Replace 'selectElemet' to 'selectElement'. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you I fixed it but still not working

Comment: Could you try this instead, $("#linkElement").mouseover(function () {
                alert('here');
                $(this).trigger("click");
            });

Comment: The 'alert' here is interfering with your trigger function. Please remove it and try, it would work.

Comment: For testing you could write a click handler for the element.  $("#linkElement").on('click',function(){
            alert('after click');
            });

Answer (score 2):

trigger('click') just happen where you have set 'click' event with element ,not physical 'click'.for example,trigger('click') even don't trigger '' tag if attach without 'click'

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#selectElement').on('change', function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the click event handler to the element. Then only it will work.

Check the below snippet.

Try placing mouse over the link and it will trigger the click event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#linkElement").mouseover(function() {
    $("#linkElement").trigger("click");
  });
  $("#linkElement").click(function(){
    window.location.href=$("#linkElement").attr("href");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="linkElement" href="www.google.co.uk">click</a>

  <select name="cars" id="selectElemet">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer . This works by redirecting the page via  window.location.href = $("#linkElement").attr("href"); on <a> tag But i need to open <select> element so not sure this will work for me

Comment: @FrankenstineJoe for that, I recomment you to use this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048213/open-select-using-javascript-jquery