# jQuery trigger select element to show options

Tags: jquery, css, select

I want to create animation placeholder for input and select element.

I use a label block on select element at first as a placeholder, then click the label or select element , in ideal, the label will move to top as a title, and select element will show its options.

However, just when I click the area of select element but outside the label will action as I though; if I clicked the label, it would just move to top but not show select element's options. It should click select element again to show options.

So, I want to trigger select element by these method as following but not working...

```js
$(document).on('click', '.moveable-disabled-option', function() {
    $(this).prev().trigger('click');
    $(this).prev().trigger('focus');
    $(this).prev().focus();
})
```

My Demo:
https://codepen.io/hsieh-po-yang/pen/yLOodyN

Comment: As I understand what you're asking, you're trying to open the `select` via javascript?  Doesn't seem to be possible; see this link for details (and numerous duplicates it links to) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652085/open-dropdown-list-from-javascript-function

Comment: You can't trigger the default `<select>` to open by script. You can however replace your select with a select replacer like `select2` (https://select2.org/) or `chosen` (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and then can trigger that dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I'll try the other method!