# Jquery dependent drop down boxes populate- how Part II

Tags: jquery

This is continued question from [Par1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910281/jquery-dependent-drop-down-boxes-populate-how).

Scenario:
I've drop down shown below.

[image]

Lets say today is *Sat, 07 May 2011 10AM*.

**Case1:** From drop down shown above, if the user selects *Fri, 06 May 2011* the hour drop  should contain *10-23*.

**Case2:**
But, if the user selects *Sat, 07 may 2011* then the Start Date Hour Drop down should contain *00-10 ie. midnight to current time*.

could anyone guide me if this is possible at all using JQuery please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
function addHoursRangeToSelect(select, from, to){
  $(select).empty();
  for(var h=from; h<=to; h++){
      $("<option />").val(h).html(addZero(n)).appendTo($(select));
  }
  function addZero(n){ return (n < 10 ? "0"+n : ""+n); }
}

$("#startDate").change(function(){
   var startHH1, endHH1;
   switch($(this).val()){
      case "2011-05-06":  //Assuming "2011-05-06" is the value of 'Fri, 06 May 2011' option
          startHH1 = 10; endHH1 = 23; break;
      case "2011-05-07": //Assuming "2011-05-06" is the value of 'Sat, 07 may 2011' option
          startHH1 = 0; endHH1 = 10; break;
   }
   addHoursRangeToSelect("#startHH1", startHH1, endHH1);
});
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Edgar. I think I must not have explained clearly. We need to populate only Start Hour Drop down (#startHH2 on your solution) from 10,11.....23 for case 1 and 0,1,2...10 for case2. I've updated the image on question so that it only shows 1 drop down.

Comment: @flybyte: Ohh, i understand now. I'm updating my solution to fullfill this requirement.