# Filter results of dropdownlist per prior dropdownlist selection using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I successfully used the jquery script TheSuperTramp posted here:

[Jquery dependent drop down boxes populate- how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910281/jquery-dependent-drop-down-boxes-populate-how?newreg=1a6bd1738dbf47a586b326de511f0656)

to remove any list items with a value less than the one selected.  However, I need to remove only the value I had selected in the first pull down menu.  I believe the following jquery script should accomplish this however it is not.  Any suggestions to correct this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
KS

```
var drop2 = $("select[id=dropdown] option"); // the collection of initial options
$("select[id=test]").change(function () {
    var drop1selected = parseInt(this.value); //get drop1 's selected value
    $("select[id=dropdown]")
                     .html(drop2) //reset dropdown list
                     .find('option').filter(function () {
                         if (parseInt(this.value) == drop1selected)
                         {
                             $(this).remove();
                         };
                     });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually need here is [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), instead of [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var drop2 = $("select[id=dropdown] option"); // the collection of initial options
$("select[id=test]").change(function () {
    var drop1selected = parseInt(this.value); //get drop1 's selected value
    $("select[id=dropdown]")
                     .html(drop2) //reset dropdown list
                     .find('option').each(function () {
                         if (parseInt(this.value) === drop1selected)
                         {
                             $(this).remove();
                         };
                     });
});
```

As `.filter()` will remove the element from the result set of matching elements, but it will not remove them from the DOM. You may want to use it like this:

```
var drop2 = $("select[id=dropdown] option"); // the collection of initial options
$("select[id=test]").change(function () {
    var drop1selected = parseInt(this.value); //get drop1 's selected value
    $("select[id=dropdown]")
                     .html(drop2) //reset dropdown list
                     .find('option').filter(function () {
                         return parseInt(this.value) === drop1selected;
                     }).remove();
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I believe your modification should have worked, however I determined due to the design of my page this function didn't suite my needs.  Instead I ended up using a Json function which updated the values from a query in my .net code.