# How to set the default value of a select box using JQuery in IE9?

Tags: jquery, select, internet-explorer-9, default-value

I have the following select box.

```
<select id="selId">
     <option id='1' value='1'>1</option>
     <option id='2' value='2'>2</option>
     <option id='3' value='3'>3</option>
     <option id='4' value='4'>4</option>
     <option id='5' value='5'>5</option>
</select>
```

In jquery I am doing the following to select the value 2 in the select box.:

```
...
$("select#selId").find("option#2").attr("selected", "selected");
...
```

The same code sets the value of 2 in the select box in IE8 and Firefox.
But its not working in IE9.

I am using JQuery 1.6.1 version

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? v1.5.1 was the first version to [support IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/02/jquery-1-5-1-supports-ie9.aspx) as a top level browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of setting the `selected` attribute, just use .val("2").

See here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwDuj/1163/)

Comment: Please remove '' from $('document')

Comment: Nope means no? Why not? $(document).ready(function() {}); but not $('document').ready(function() {}); and your jsfiddle doesn't work because of that at least when I click on the link. Once I remove ' ', it loads fine.

Answer (score 5):

Anyway, this worked well on **IE9** if you want to mantain the `"SELECTED"` attribute

```
$("select#selId").find("option#2").attr("selected", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cqENs/

Comment: +1 nice answer. A much nicer approach to actually maintain the attribute. I actually thought val() would do it behind the scenes but it doesn't!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val#val) to set the option instead - see [Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery/499413#499413)

Answer (score 1):

change this one

```
$("select#selId").find("option#2").attr("selected", "selected");
```

into this one

```
$("select#selId").find("option#2").attr("selected", true);
```