# I need to display the text "Select the one" in the combo box by default

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, selection

I'm creating a combo box which loads options from JSON..Its loading the menus as expected.But I need to display the text "Select the one" in the combo box by default. I tried but can't find the solution..Can you advice me,How can i achieve it?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);    

    for (var i=0; i < obj.MenuParentTabs.length; i++)    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");    
        option.innerHTML = obj.MenuParentTabs[i].parentTabName;
        document.form1.fruits.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help to also show us your relevant HTML, or construct a simple example on jsfiddle.

Comment: just initialize the select using `<select id="fruits"><option value="">Select the one</option></select>` an empty `<select>` isn't valid HTML anyways.

Comment: [Really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329580/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-select-box-using-jquery-in-ie9)?? [You](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element) [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212939/set-default-text-in-a-select-drop-down-box-menu) for a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the `option` with the text you want, **before** the `for` loop:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "Select the one";
document.form1.fruits.appendChild(option);
```

If the `option` isn't the first child of the `select` (i.e. you don't put it before the `for`  loop for some reason), also set the `selected` attribute as well:

```
option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

Complete code to help the OP:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);    

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = "Select the one";
    option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    document.form1.fruits.appendChild(option);

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.MenuParentTabs.length; i++) {
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = obj.MenuParentTabs[i].parentTabName;
        document.form1.fruits.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also add selected to this option and maybe a "disabled" to it as well? Or use Javascript to remove it when the menu is shown.

Comment: @Asitaka, if it's the first option, it's already selected by default... And about the `disabled` suggestion, of course the OP can do it. Since it wasn't said in the question, I'll left it open in the answer.

Comment: This is true, but the OP might add options or do something that changes the order, specifying "selected" forces it to be selected no matter the order.

Comment: Ok, I explained a little better in case they don't put the code before the `for` loop.

Comment: @ErickPetru : I did as you mentioned above,But I am getting only the last item from the loop in the combo box.

Comment: @rightPath, I updated my answer with the complete code. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting something like this before your for loop:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");    
option.innerHTML = "Select One";
document.form1.fruits.appendChild(option);
```

I can also highly recommend jQuery for these kind of shenanigans.

Comment: @hhamitlton :  I did as you mentioned above,But I am getting only the last item from the loop in the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar question and answer over here:

[HTML select: how to set default text which won't be shown in drop-down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447134/html-select-how-to-set-default-text-which-wont-be-shown-in-drop-down-list)

```
basically do this:
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "Select the one";
option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
option.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
document.form1.fruits.appendChild(option);
```

and I suppose if you really wanted to be thorough, you could add something that hides this option when the menu appears.