# jQuery selector for select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have the follow code

```
$("#tlbQueryConf tr:last").append(
    $('<td></td>').append(
        $(".ddlFields").clone().attr('id', 'ddlFields-' + conf.id).attr('class', '').val(conf.field)));
```

So now, what i'm trying to accomplish it's give the attribute `selected` to the new element with that value that i selected

i tried like this, but sets the atribute `selected` to the element and not the item

```
$(".ddlFields").clone().attr('id', 'ddlFields-' + conf.id).attr('class', '').val(conf.field).attr('selected',true)
```

the html that result its the follow

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlFields" id="ddlFields-1" class="">
    <option value="1">Prueba</option>
    <option value="2">cantidad de fallas</option>
    <option value="3">nº</option>
    <option value="4">Ciudad</option>
    <option value="5">COID</option>
    <option value="6">COID_DESC</option>
    <option value="7">Creado_EN</option>
    <option value="8">DSLAM PROVEEDOR</option>
</select>
```

#### Note

even using `val()` the property `selected` it's not set to item

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)

Comment: 'selected' is a property not an attribute. You should use `prop()` to set it.

Comment: @Abe Miessler  sure give me one second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (and correct me if I misunderstood), you want to change the selection of the drop down list?

You can do that like this:

```
$(".ddlFields").val("value of the item you want selected");
```

and you can retrieve the selected value like this:

```
$(".ddlFields").val();
```

You don't have to worry about setting the `selected` attribute your self, jquery handles that for you when you set the value of the list.

See this duplicate question for more information:  [Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)

Comment: i thinked exactly the same but when inspect the html, the option doesn't have the attribute `selected`

Comment: When that script is executed, does the value of the list change?  What browser are you using?  Some browsers don't reflect changes caused by scripts in their "view source" features.

Comment: in the view of the browser the item it's change with my value but in the html, the item doesn't have the property set. I added the html. I'm using chrome

Comment: Why are you concerned that the `selected` property is being set, if the value is changing as expected?

Comment: because, in other part of my script i need that value and when i getting the value doesn't give the same item display in the browser

Comment: To get the selected value of the dropdown you can call `.val() `without any arguments:  var value = $(".ddlFields").val();

Comment: I know but it doesn't give me the same value that I'm setting

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a `selected=selected` attribute to the `select` element when you should be selecting one of the options. Try this:

```
$("#tlbQueryConf tr:last").append(
    $('<td>', {
        html: $(".ddlFields").clone()
            .attr({'id':'ddlFields-' + conf.id,'class':''}).val(conf.field)
    })
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/aEVt2/

Answer (score 1):

Which item are you trying to select? As per your code it will add selected attribute to the select tag. You should specify the option to select. Try this

```
$(".ddlFields").clone().attr({ 'id': 'ddlFields-' + conf.id, 'class': ''}).val(conf.field);
```