# add value top select option when li is click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Need help with this, I have this list that I need to link on my select drop-down option, and I need a jQuery code to do this.

```
<ul class="north">
    <span class="label"><strong>North Island</strong></span>
    <li><a href="#" id="map1" class="northland">Northland</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="map2" class="aukland">Auckland</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#" id="map3" class="waikato">Waikato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="map4" class="bayofplenty">Bay of Plenty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="map5" class="gisborne">Gisborne & Hawkes Bay</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="map6" class="taranaki">Taranaki</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="map7" class="manawatu">Manawatu & Wanganui</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="map8" class="wellington">Wellington</a></li>
</ul>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="nort">Northland Stockist</option>
    <option value="aukland">Aukland Stockist</option>
    <option value="waikato">waikato Stockist</option>
    <option value="bay of plent">Bay of Plenty Stockist</option>
    <option value="gisborne">Gisborne & Hawkes Bay Stockist</option>
    <option value="taranaki">Taranaki Stockist</option>
    <option value="manawatu">Manawatu & Wanganui Stockist</option>
    <option value="wellington">Wellington Stockist </option>
    <option value="nelson">Nelson & Marlborough Stockist</option>
    <option value="westcost">west coast Stockist</option>
    <option value="canterbuty">canterbury Stockist</option>
    <option value="otago">otago &  Sounthland Stockist</option>
</select>
```

What I need to do is when I click the `<li>Northland</li>` the select option that has class "norhtland" will appear and the rest will appear depend on the `li` class that I clicked. Hope someone can help me on this. Thanks so much

Comment: I can't find any classes with select options?? what do u mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We can help you with code that isn't working but you should at least make some attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: Also, you can't use a `span` as a direct child of a `ul`. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: This question is essentially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery with an added string search, did you Google this before you asked it?

Comment: You have try something first. Then we all will help you to solve the issue. Show some `JQuery` that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("ul.north li a").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#select2").val($(this).attr("class"));

var options = $("#select2 option");
var activeClass = $(this).attr("class");

options.each(function(i,e){

    var t = $(this);

    if(t.val() == activeClass){

        t.show();
    }else{
         t.hide();   
    }

})

});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmv8V/11/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("ul.north li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#select2").val($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

NOTE : li a tag class and option value should be same ,then only it work

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmv8V/5/)

Comment: this code is working, but how can i remove the other value on select option that doesn't have the same class with li? Thanks again

Comment: @labli in single select dropdown, only one value can be selected at a time. So, when you will make some value as selected, other value will be got unseleted automatically.

Comment: @raj, what i want to do is something like this one http://fiddle.jshell.net/7m2xt/1/ , only the value of option in select box will appear depending on the li class.. sorry if i wasn't clear on that

Answer (score 0):

You must try something first, anyways..

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.north li a').click(function() {
        $('#select2').val($(this).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5kP7/1/)

**EDIT:** As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033444/add-value-top-select-option-when-li-is-click/25033799?noredirect=1#comment38935729_25033799)

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="north">North</option>
    <option value="south">South</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="north">North 1</option>
    <option value="north">North 1</option>
    <option value="south">South 1</option>
    <option value="south">South 1</option>
</select>

$(function () {
    $('#select1').click(function () {
        $('#select2 option').hide();
        $('#select2 option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop("selected",true).show();
    });
});
```

Here is updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5kP7/8/)

Comment: Nothing new now :P, I was written the answer and pressed submit 40 min ago and just left the desk... after coming back I seen an error in submission.. I didn't have seen your ans so just submitted my answer after correction. So, it posted after yours... I think I can remove it now... because both the answers are similar

Comment: You have to use like this for selecting element   $('#select2 option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop("selected",true).show();