# How to change the setected default value in a 2nd drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have two drop down list "optionone" and "optiontwo" and I want to change the default selected value from "option value=3>3" to option value=3 selected>3 when 2 is selected from my first dropdown list ("optionone")

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
    var mylist = document.getElementById("optionone");
        var myvalue = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].value

        if (myvalue == 2) {
        //do stuff
    document.getElementById("optiontwo")
        //Change <option value=3>3 to <option value=3 selected>3
        }

}
</script>
```

My drop down list

```
<select name="optionone" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value=1>1
  <option value=2>2
  <option value=3>3
  <option value=4>4
  <option value=5>5
  <option value=6>6
</select>

<select name="optiontwo">
  <option value=1>1
  <option value=2>2
  <option value=3>3
  <option value=4>4
  <option value=5>5
  <option value=6>6
</select>
```

Which I want to change to the following when 2 is select from my first drop down list (optionone)

```
<select name="optiontwo">
  <option value=1>1
  <option value=2>2
  <option value=3 selected>3
  <option value=4>4
  <option value=5>5
  <option value=6>6
</select>
```

I'm a bit stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a invalid `markup`, `<option>` must be closed
2. There is no `id` attribute for second select input
3. You can set the `value` attribute instead of finding the option value using index.
4. `value` should be wrapped in `quote`
5. Instead of playing with `selected` attribute, setting the value will make `option` selected.
6. Instead of `inline-event-binding`, use `addEventListener`

```js
/*
function myFunction(elem) {
  document.getElementById("optiontwo").value = elem.value;
}
*/
document.getElementById('optionone').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById("optiontwo").value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<select name="optionone" id="optionone" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
</select>
<select name="optiontwo" id='optiontwo'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**remove onChange="" from html**

And update you code or markup like this ..

```
<select name="optionone" id="optionone">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
</select>
<select name="optiontwo" id='optiontwo'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
</select>
```

and then add this javascript code

```
 document.getElementById('optionone').addEventListener('change',
 function() {
    if(this.value == 2){
       document.getElementById("optiontwo").value = 3;
    }
 });
```

and your problem will solve

Comment: This is jquery so I would need to add the jquery library for this to work, which it does

Comment: @Rich see my example i updated that so you can get javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above I adapted Rayon's script to update as I wanted, as follows

```
<script>
document.getElementById('optionone').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 2){
       document.getElementById("optiontwo").value = 3;
    }
});
</script>
```