# Using jQuery to create and then select options in a <select>

Tags: jquery, selected

I have a popup form which populates the `<options>` of a `<select>` from its parent form. Each `<option>` has a different `value` from the text displayed.

However, if I programmatically set the selected option in the popup via:

```
$("#id option[val='" + window.opener.$("#id").val() + "']").prop('selected', true);
```

Then jQuery sets the option value in the popup form to that of the option text in the parent form.

Comment: Just target the `select` instead and call val(). jQuery will select the matching `option`.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question are not clear. Help us to help you. Post your code using our tag's to identify a code block on your question. Show us the hole code you have tryed to allow us run your code and try also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)