# Cascading Drop Drown - 2nd Drop Down Coming with "Unknown" But Correct Number of Items

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In an attempt of doing a cascading dropdown, I followed [this](https://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-cascading-dropdown-list.html) good tutorial. But I made a few changes through out the process.
Summing up, I have two dropdowns where one should control the other. The first one is working well, it returns the data that I expect. 
The second one, it returns the correct amount that I expect, however, all the different items come as "unknown".

For example, I choose a name on the 1st dropdown the 2nd dropwdown changes to the correct amountt of items related to the 1st dropdown but the information/items comes as unknown.

On my .cshtml, I have

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VId, "vendor")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VId, ViewBag.VendorName as SelectList, "--Select Vendor--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IFID, "family")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IFID, ViewBag.FamilyName as SelectList, "--Select Family--", new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
```

Also, on my .cshtml, I have the part where I am creating the jquery script:

```
@section scripts {

    <script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function ()
            {
            //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
            $("#VId").change(function ()
            {
                $("#IFID").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("SelectFamilies")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: $("#VId").val() },
                    success: function (families)
                    {
                        alert($("#VId").val());
                        alert(families.dataType);

                        $.each(families, function (i, family)
                        {
                            $("#IFID").append('<option value="'
                                + family.IFID + '">'
                                + family.IndexFamilyName + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex)
                    {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex.responseText);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });

    </script>
}
```

On this .cshtml, I am pointing to a @model that defines the variables this way:

```
public virtual ICollection<IFDto> families { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<VDto> vendors { get; set; }

public virtual VDto vendor { get; set; }
public virtual IFDto family { get; set; }
```

"@Url.Action("SelectFamilies")" comes from (this is in a controller):

```
public JsonResult SelectFamilies(int id)
    {
        //IEnumerable<IFDto> families = db.states.Where(stat => stat.country_id == id);
        IEnumerable<IFDto> families = _indexfamilyDataGateway.GetFamiliesByVendor(id);
        return Json(families);
    }
```

Also, on this same controller I have:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //ViewBag.VendorName = GetVendorSelectItems();
        //ViewBag.FamilyName = GetFamilySelectItems();

        ViewBag.VendorName = new SelectList(_vendorDataGateway.GetAll(), "VId", "AbbrevAndName");
        ViewBag.FamilyName = new SelectList(_indexfamilyDataGateway.GetAll(), "IFID", "IFName");


   return View();
    }
```

This is a similar problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery).

In one of the comments, it was requested (and also a good idea) for me to do a "console.log(families)" inside the .ajax success. It is returning the information that I need:
[image]
Please, noticed that it is printing 4 times because I put the "console." before and after the .ajax success "each" statement. If I just put after success and before the $.each it returns an array.

Comment: If you `console.log(families)` inside your `success` function of `ajax`, what it will log?

Comment: @Ammar , I just added on my original questions an image with my output. It is coming as "Array(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]".

Answer (score 0):

With a good idea, provided by @Ammar, of using "console.log(families)" I was able to figure it out that inside the .ajax $.each I was wrongly using:

```
+ family.IFID + '">'
+ family.IndexFamilyName +
```

When I should be using:

```
+ family.iFID + '">'
+ family.indexFamilyName +
```

The problem was the wrong use of an uppercase letter after the ".".