# Unable to set selected attribute of dropdown using Jquery 3.4.1, c# mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set default value in dropdown when HTML page is loaded. I have filled the dropdown values dynamically from code as `0` = Select, `1` = Required and `2` = Not Required

I have written below line of code to set the value as "Required".

```
$("#ddltest option:contains('Required')").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

However the "Not Required" option is getting set.

C# fiddler link below: https://dotnetfiddle.net/llbCf3

Comment: That's because "not required" *does* contain "required"

Comment: If you know the values, you can use them directly: `$("#ddltest").val(1)`.  In the same way that you're checking if `.val() == 0` in the line above.

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery

Comment: If you need to find by exact text, then you need to use .filter - see the answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/496126/2181514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is there are 2 text have **Required**, you can change your jquery code to

```
$("#ddltest option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Required';
}).prop("selected", true);
```

Demo at dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/cez5QB